# Is the package ucharclasses  not included in TeX Live?

Tags: texlive, ucharclasses

I have completed the net install of TeX Live 2011 on Linux. I am trying to install the `ucharclasses` package through tlmgr but it seems that the package is missing.

I am using [this mirror](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/). According to [this report](http://dante.ctan.org/mirmon/) it is synced. Just to be sure, I tried with other mirrors too, but to no avail. I checked the files at the server at path `ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/` and the file is indeed missing.

Am I doing something wrong, or the package is just not included in the distribution?

ps. I can always install it manually (eg get it from `ctan/macros/xetex/latex/`) but i'd really prefer to be able to do it through the manager (auto updates etc).

Comment: I tried to make the title a bit more specific, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @doncherry Cool with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ucharclasses version 2.0 has been released and this version has a GPL compatible license so from now on it is going to be part of the TeXLive releases. Look [here](https://github.com/Pomax/ucharclasses/issues/1) for more info.

Answer (score 9):

From the `README` file:

> This package was written by Mike "Pomax" Kamermans, from
>    nihongoresources and is © 2010, Michiel Kamermans. You
>    may freely use this package, but you are discouraged from
>    modifying this package and then redistributing it. Instead,
>    please contact me (ideally on the XeTeX mailing list) and
>    we can discuss the changes you wish to make. If they
>    benefit everyone, they will be worked in as a new version.

Unfortunately this may qualify the package as "nonfree". Would Mike Kamermans adhere to the LPPL license (or another free one), his package would be in TeX Live. It was included for a short time after its submission to CTAN, but it was withdrawn some days later for licensing problems.

Comment: How I despise this "free" / "nonfree" nonsense...

Comment: @DevSolar It's quite a nuisance, some times; but the TeX Live people don't like the risk to be sued or, more likely, that TeX Live is pushed off some GNU/Linux distribution for including "nonfree" stuff to their distribution. Can we blame them for this?

Comment: No, but we can blame the GNU/FSF people for making it a matter of holy war, "if you are not with me you are against me" thing in the first place.

Comment: You can always fork TeXLive and do things TeXLive developers refuse to do, like including non-free software. Complaining and "despising" will get you nowhere.

Comment: @egreg -- there's another reason for not including "non-free" items in tex live.  with all its contents fully free, tex live can be included with os distributions and copies of the cd can be included in books like the companion.  with even one non-free item in the collection, this would be legally impossible.

Comment: @barbara beeton: ...and nothing in Mike's license statement keeps you from doing that.

Comment: @DevSolar What I know is that **ucharclasses** appeared in TeX Live just after its submission to CTAN, but was withdrawn a couple of days later. I don't know whether Mike has changed the license afterwards; if one is interested in having this package in TeX Live should contact the [texlive mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live) to ask for detailed information.

Comment: @DevSolar -- the catalogue entry for the package lists the license as "other nonfree licenses".  while this may be subjective on the part of the person making the catalogue entry, the statement in the readme discouraging unapproved changes does justify that decision.

Comment: @barbara beeton: And that's the point I've been trying to make: The FSF considers it their right to determine what is "free" and "compatible" licensing, and they decided that "free to copy" isn't "free" enough to be "compatible", so "free to copy" became second-rate software. In the warped world of the FSF, bad software that is "free" is better than quality software that you aren't allowed to fork and mutilate. *That's* what I despise.

Comment: @DevSolar: If you're unhappy with the current situation, feel free to create a package on tlcontrib: one of the goals of this alternate package repository for TeX Live is precisely to accept material that is not included in TL due to licence issues. And since TL 2012 it's easy to use both repositories (tlnet + tlcontrib) at the same time.