# TeXLive 2011 Upgrading to the latest packages tug.org

Tags: installing, texlive

How do I update the TexLive 2011 with the latest packages available on [tug.org](http://tug.org) using the `tlgmr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all described on the [`tlmgr` TUG website](http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html). From the command prompt, you can type

```
tlmgr update --self --all
```

This should update the actual TeX Live manager `tlmgr` (by virtue of `--self`), as well as update all installed package (via `--all`).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you may use the GUI

```
tlmgr --gui
```

This way you can search for packages in CTAN too (most of them actually, as [not all of them are supported by TexLive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28643/is-the-package-ucharclasses-not-included-in-tex-live)).

Needless to say, depending on your platform and the way you installed TexLive you may or you may not need root privileges.